# Fabric.js save transformMatrix

Tags: fabricjs

Saving the canvas with toJSON and loading with fromJSON working but the state of transformMatrix was not added to JSON.
Does anybody know, how to add the transformMatrix data to json?

Comment: Here is a sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/ud406L0e/

Comment: This is a typical case of: asking on SO is faster than reading docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old version of fabric did not carry on the transforMatrix.
Newer version (1.6.0-rc1 and higher ) does properly.

For older version do:

```
myJson = canvas.toJson(['transformMatrix']);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ud406L0e/1/
check updated fiddle.